# Inserting pch data point symbols into axis labels in R

Tags: r, text, plot, axis-labels, pch

I have combined two data sets into one graph and I would like to add the corresponding `pch` symbols right into the axis labels. 
Now, I know that solutions using `text()` instead of `xlab` and `ylab` and Hershey vector fonts (instead of citing a `pch=16`, etc.) are given [here](http://www.thinkoholic.com/2012/02/13/insert-pch-data-point-symbols-text-axis-labels/) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-March/019415.html) but the symbols appear kinda wonky-shaped. Does anyone have a more "well-rounded" solution?

thinkoholic.com's reproducible example,

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,5))

# create data and plot circles
x <- seq(0,5,0.5)

y <- seq(0,5,0.5)
plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="")

#create random data and add bullets (pch=19)
x <- rnorm(20,2.5)
y <- rnorm(20,2.5)
points(x,y, pch=19)

#add y axis on right side
axis (side = 4)

#create text with symbols
text(-1,2.5,"\\#H0850 y1 axis text", vfont=c("sans serif","plain"), cex=1.25, adj=0.5, srt=90, xpd=TRUE)
text(6,2.5,"\\#H0902 y2 axis text", vfont=c("sans serif","plain"), cex=1.25, adj=0.5, srt=90, xpd=TRUE)
text(2.5,-1,"x axis text", vfont=c("sans serif","plain"), cex=1.25, adj=0.5, srt=0, xpd=TRUE)
```

Comment: One option, if the distortion is not solvable, is to not draw axes on your original plot(s) and to draw the plot larger than it needs to be on `xlim` and `ylim`. Then go back in and draw axes using `text` within the expanded plot area rather than in the margins and your `points` will be in the plotting space rather than margins and should not be distorted. That's sort of a hack, though, and I'm sure someone has a better idea.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. Also, I recommend not to do this. While I do not fully agree with the opinion that secondary axes should never be used, I strongly believe that symbols besides the data points should only appear in a legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing this:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,5), xpd=TRUE)

x <- seq(0,5,0.5)
y <- seq(0,5,0.5)
plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="")


text(-1,2.5,"y axis text", cex=1.25, adj=0, srt=90)
points(-1,2.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mtext(paste0("your label text", " (",  intToUtf8(9679), ")"), side = 2, line=2.5)
```